# SBT Test - Ignore excludes and run everything

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a Play framework with a bunch of tests (which are run with ScalaTest), and I am trying to organize them by:

- Unit test
- Integration Test Read
- Integration Test Write

I have left all of my unit tests untagged, and have created the following tags:

```
/* TestTags.scala */

object IntegrationReadTest extends Tag("IntegrationReadTest")
object IntegrationWriteTest extends Tag("IntegrationWriteTest")
```

so that I can tag my integration tests like this:

```
/* SomeSpecs.scala */

"foo" taggedAs IntegrationReadTest in {
  // External APIs are read from
}

"bar" taggedAs IntegrationWriteTest in {
  // External APIs are written to
}
```

Most of the time while I am developing and running tests, I do **not** want to run the integration tests, so I modified my `build.sbt` to ignore them when I run `sbt test`:

```
/* build.sbt */

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-l", "IntegrationReadTest")
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-l", "IntegrationWriteTest")
```

This all works well, but I cannot figure how to run all of the tests (including the integration tests).  I have tried many combinations of `sbt test` and `sbt "test:testOnly"` but can not figure out how to un-ignore the integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

By default, your tests run in the Test context.  This means that sbt test is really doing `sbt Test/test`.  Since you are setting `testOptions in Test`, this applies by default.

From that, it follows that you can create a new context `All` which puts those tests back in.

```
/* build.sbt */

lazy val All = config("all") extend(Test) describedAs("run all the tests")
configs(All)
inConfig(All)(Defaults.testSettings)

testOptions in All -= Tests.Argument("-l", "IntegrationReadTest")
testOptions in All -= Tests.Argument("-l", "IntegrationWriteTest")
```

Then you can run `sbt All/test` to run them all.